# CakePHP 3.6: A non-numeric value encountered when submitting empty numeric field

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

How I can set the numeric value to 0 if the submitted control is empty? This is my control:

```
echo $this->Form->control('paid', ['label' => 'Paid', 'type'=>'number']);
```

Comment: If it's just this one field, then the `beforeMarshal` callback is probably what you want.

Comment: You can simply set default value = 0 of paid column in your table.

Comment: @Sehdev, that might also require changes to validation.